# If mother is superior to father then why did Parashurama kill his mother on his father's command?

Tags: parashurama, parents, renuka

We know that Parashurama [killed](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03116.htm) his mother Renuka without a blink on his father's Jamadgani's command. But [Manusmriti 2.145](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199615.html) says

> In veneration, the Preceptor excels ten Sub-teachers; the Father a hundred preceptors, and the Mother a thousand Fathers.

So why did Parashurama obey his father's command ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104545/discussion-on-question-by-carmen-sandiego-if-mother-is-superior-to-father-then-w).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did Parashurama perform any expiation for killing his mother?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35357/did-parashurama-perform-any-expiation-for-killing-his-mother)

Comment: @CR241 - No it doesn't. I am interested in why he did it first place. If logic is that he was aware of what is going to happen in future (i.e. his father bring back his mother to life , and he being pardoned for the same ) then with such reductionism can very well be extended to everything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why did Parashurama obey his father's command ?

This is answered in the [Srimad Bhagavatam](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/9/16/):

> राम: सञ्चोदित: पित्रा भ्रातृन् मात्रा सहावधीत् ।
> **प्रभावज्ञो मुने: सम्यक् समाधेस्तपसश्च** स: ॥ ६ ॥
>
> Jamadagni then ordered his youngest son, Paraśurāma, to kill his brothers, who had disobeyed this order, and his mother, who had mentally committed adultery. Lord Paraśurāma, **knowing the power of his father, who was practiced in meditation and austerity**, killed his mother and brothers immediately.

> उत्तस्थुस्ते कुशलिनो निद्रापाय इवाञ्जसा ।
> पितुर्विद्वां**स्तपोवीर्यं** रामश्चक्रे सुहृद्वधम् ॥ ८ ॥
>
> Thereafter, by the benediction of Jamadagni, Lord Paraśurāma’s mother and brothers immediately came alive and were very happy, as if awakened from sound sleep. Lord Paraśurāma had killed his relatives in accordance with his father’s order **because he was fully aware of his father’s power, austerity and learning.**

But nowhere does this Purana say that this killing was in accordance with dharma. In fact, the [Mahabharata says](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03116.htm) this was done out of wrath:

> And mighty and powerful and of a wrathful turn of mind...

Also, Apastamba sutra 1.1.2.19 says:

> Ācārya adhīnaḥ syād anyatra patanīyebhyaḥ || 19 ||
>
> 19. He shall obey his teacher, except [when ordered to commit] crimes which cause loss of caste.

Killing the mother is a *mahapataka*, which is worse than a sin which merely causes "loss of caste".

And [Manusmriti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200267.html) 4.162 prohibits this killing:

> He shall not injure his Preceptor, or Teacher or Father, **or mother**, or another elder, or Brāhmaṇas, or Cows, or any persons performing austerities.

Moreover, the [Mahabharata passage](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03116.htm) here explicitly says that this killing was sinful:

> sa vavre mātur utthānam asmṛtiṃ ca vadhasya vai |
> pāpena tena cāsparśaṃ bhrātṝṇāṃ prakṛtiṃ tathā ||
>
> He chose for his mother to be brought back to life and forget the killing,  non-contact with that sin (for himself), and for his brothers to be brought back to life.

Comment: Interesting..so his brothers were not aware of their father's powers ? Moreover how does Parashurama know that his father will grant a boon post acting upon the latter's order?

Comment: @Carmensandiego Maybe his brothers also knew, but they were shocked at the thought of killing their mom. Also, Parashurama is an avesha avatar of Vishnu. He is special.

Comment: where it is mentioned that parasurama is Avesha avatara not avatara.. Parasurama is Avatara of vishnu who killed kirti virya arjuna  of thousand hand and immense power, Kriti virya arjuna kept Ravana in prison by just using his hand. Parasurama is able to kill kritivirya arjuna easily.. And also only god knowns the future and internal working of minds or the atonmnet for acts committed

Comment: 1. Washer man killing when krishna asked for clothes of king he refused stating that its kamsa clothes but washerman is just obeying why killed by srikrishna.

Comment: See the act of thought while performing severe austerity will pollute the whole yagna of jamadagni resulting in whole family going down in next birth, jamadagni knows this as atonment he prescribed this pusnishnment knowingly he can revive with his power.

Comment: @PrasannaR It is the belief of Sri Vaishnava acharyas that Parashurama is krodha-avesha-avatara of Narayana. "jamadagni knows this as atonment he prescribed this pusnishnment knowingly he can revive with his power." - I have heard this before too.

Comment: Parasurama according to legend still lives in Mahendragiri of Tamilnadu kerala border.

Comment: I feel the argument being an avatar gives him knowledge of past , presence and future can basically be extended to all other avatars as well and can result in tremendous reductionism , and therefore little to no knowledge of dharma can then be obtained from scriptures. Unless the scripture mentions that avatar explicitly cited this as the reason I find it difficult to accept that knowledge of future argument @Ikshvaku

Comment: @Carmensandiego Yeah I also feel the same way as you. People try very hard to explain "uncomfortable" things in scripture like parashurama's killing of his mom, draupadi's polyandry, pandavas' acceptance of the polyandry, Rama's banishment of sita to the forest, etc. People come up with all sorts of stories that either don't exist in the text at all, or are interpolations. But, regarding parashurama's killing, the scripture itself says that parashurama says it was sinful, and he says he did it due to fear of his father's power.

Answer (score 3):

What Manu smriti stated is a general rule, when everything is going on in normal way.

However, in the instant case, [Renuka got swayed away](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03116.htm) by the charms of the King Chitraratha's appearance and her mind got polluted.  Hence, the general rule of Manu Smriti cannot be applied here and hence, the orders of father got precedence.

> Now once upon a time, when her sons had gone out for the purpose of
> gathering fruits, Renuka who had a pure and austere life, went out to
> bathe. And, O king, while returning home, she happened to cast her
> glance towards the king of Martikavata, known by the name of
> Chitraratha.
>
> The king was in the water with his wives, and wearing on
> his breast a lotus wreath, was engaged in sport. And ***beholding his
> magnificent form***, Renuka was inspired ***with desire***. And this unlawful
> desire she could not control, but became polluted within the water,
> and came back to the hermitage frightened at heart.
>
> Her husband
> readily perceived what state she was in. And mighty and powerful and
> of a wrathful turn of mind, when he beheld that she had been giddy and
> that the lustre of chastity had abandoned her, ***he reproached her*** by
> crying out 'Fie!'

Comment: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201378.html

Comment: @Ketan: Do you want me to include this issue in my answer?

Comment: If you think if it make sense then pls do. I think this verse gives an impression that superiority feeling towards mother goes away when she is unfaithful. Thank you

Comment: Parshurama didn't know that his mother's mind had wandered. Besides the atonement for a woman's mind wandering is not death.

Comment: @Carmensandiego: We should not view and understand everything that occurred long ago, with the present view of mind.  Thus customs, way of life, etc of that era have to be kept in mind while understanding those issues.  Rama of Jamadagni knows his parents well.  Till then , there was no complaint from his father towards his mother.  All of a sudden, if father order his mother to be killed means, something might have happened.  It was mentioned in the Mahabharata that Rama of Jamadagni surpassed his brother in everything

Comment: I am not at all referring to present view of mind. I am referring to what dharma sastras say. And Dharma sastras do mention that mind wandering is not punishable by death

Comment: @Carmensandiego: Dharma Sastras are for general guidance only, for smooth functioning of day to day life.  they are not ultimate.Aitareya Brahmana narrates story of Sunasepha, who was sold away by his father, but later rescued by Viswamitra.  Thus, after that incident Sunasepha takes shelter at Viswamitra, who was his preceptor.  Did not this against Manu Smriti 2.145, which says Father takes precedence over the preceptor?  **Dharma is very subtle**.  We have to understand this aspect.

Comment: I don't accept that Dharma shastras were for guidance only. It is clearly mentioned that the order of precedence starts with Shruti , then smritis , then learned men/community etc. As far as story of sunasepha is concerned , it does not help one bit here. Details there included that father had given away all rights, visvamitra was his new father etc.

Comment: @Carmensandiego: I had stated how to view the Dharma Sastras.  You are at liberty to accept or reject my opinion.  Thanks

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Can we change our Dharma as per our conscience due to the times we live (as compared to ancient time or so)?

Comment: As per my understanding, Dharma is very subtle.  It should be understood based on 3 parameters, ie, Time,place and local custom. For example:in the present scenario, marriage between cousins in North India is not acceptable but is acceptable in South India. In Mahabharata Arjuna and Subhadra got married inspite of being cousins. @JohnRay

Answer (score 3):

After reading Medhātithi’s commentary in Manusmriti 2.145 and 2.146, it seems that I might have an answer. Turns out Parashurama obeyed the orders because he didn't consider them to come from his father but from his "Guru" (i.e. person who taught him Vedas) who also happened to be his father.

From Manusmriti [2.146](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199616.html)

> Between the progenitor and the imparter of the veda, the imparter of the veda is the more venerable father; for the brāhmaṇa’s “birth” is the veda, eternally,—here as well as after death.—(146)

Now this seems to be contradicts 2.145. And Manusmriti [2.171](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199646.html) in support of 2.146 adds

> They call the Teacher “father,” on account of his imparting the Veda. Before the tying of the girdle, the performance of no religious act is proper for him.

Now the transliterated 2.145 verse is

> upādhyāyān daśācārya ācāryāṇāṃ śataṃ pitā |
>   sahasraṃ tu pitṝn mātā gauraveṇātiricyate || 145 ||

And the seemingly contradiction with Manusmriti 2.146 is explained by Medhātithi as follows

> Ācārya’ is not one who teaches; hence in the present verse the term stands for one who only performs the sacramental rites and teaches merely the rules of conduct;—Ācārya being one who makes one learn ā cāra....From all this it is clear that the superiority of the father here meant is only over that person who confers upon one only a slight benefit, who only performs the Initiatory Rite and teaches the Rules of Conduct, and does not do any teaching.

Thus dharma was upheld as Parashurama obeyed his Guru's command who is superior to parents

Comment: "Thus dharma was upheld as Parashurama obeyed his Guru's command who is superior to parents" - However, Apastamba sutra 1.1.2.19 says: Ācārya adhīnaḥ syād anyatra patanīyebhyaḥ || 19 || "He shall obey his teacher, except [when ordered to commit] crimes which cause loss of caste." - Killing mother is a *mahatpAtaka*, which is worse than a sin that causes "loss of caste".

Comment: @Ikshvaku - I have a doubt..Not limited to Parashurama slaying his mother incident. How does a student know if he is comitting a sinful act by following his guru's orders? I mean only a Guru can tell what is sinful and what is not

Comment: Realistically, one has multiple gurus. A child learns from multiple sources: parents, friends, society, teachers, police, king, leaders, etc. In a Vedapatashala, students have an adhyapaka (teacher) for Veda adhyayana, for Sanskrit, etc., just like modern classrooms. In some cases they have one teacher for everything. This teacher can be their father or someone else they live with. But, as always, kids learn from multiple sources. Today we have the internet.